# Convert a SOAP response with CDATA to JSON in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have this kind result of coming from a soap response in mule 4.

`{ body:<web:getRoutesResponse xmlns:web="http://www.example.org/Bookings/"> <out><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?><ROUTELIST><ROUTEINFO> <ORIGIN>MY-KUL</ORIGIN><DESTINATION>SG-BEU</DESTINATION><ROUTEINFO></ROUTELIST>]]></out> </web:getRoutesResponse> , headers: [], attachments: [] }`

I want to make in this json output which have array of origin and destination

`[ { "origin": "MY-KUL", "destination": "SG-BEU" } ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of that CDATA element is a textual representation of an XML. For DataWeave it is just text. You can use read() to parse it as XML and then process it normally.

For example something like

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
read(payload.body.out, "application/xml").ROUTELIST.*ROUTEINFO
```

You might need to map the result if you want the tags in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the something like this. On the same lines as previous answer from Ale, though uses scan to search for content between certain patterns of text.

**Input**

```
{
    "body": "<web:getRoutesResponse xmlns:web=\"http: //www.example.org/Bookings/\"> <out><![CDATA[<?xml version=\"1.0\"encoding=\"utf-8\"?><ROUTELIST><ROUTEINFO> <ORIGIN>MY-KUL</ORIGIN><DESTINATION>SG-BEU</DESTINATION><ROUTEINFO></ROUTELIST>]]></out> </web:getRoutesResponse>",
    "headers": [],
    "attachments": []
}
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var a = read(payload.body, "application/xml").getRoutesResponse.out
---
[{
    origin: (a scan(/\<ORIGIN>(.+?)\<\/ORIGIN>/))[0][1],
    desination: (a scan(/\<DESTINATION>(.+?)\<\/DESTINATION>/))[0][1]
}]
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "origin": "MY-KUL",
    "desination": "SG-BEU"
  }
]
```